# Authenticating Access to Django Rest Framework using custom authentication from a Django App

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ldap, django-authentication, django-rest-auth

Ive implemented a custom auth system in one(only) Django app on my project
Now I want to open my site up to Api access, is there a way to only let users from the Django app access this api. As I don't want to repeat myself (DRY) so was asking if it was possible to work backwards rather than to overwrite the Django rest Authentication with very similar code

Answer (score 0):

DRF's `SessionAuthentication` is included in the default DRF settings and is entirely transparent to users who are already familiar with logging in to your site.  You can add it to the list of authenticators for DRF:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        # ...
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

The session a user establishes when logging in to your site now also authenticates them for DRF's browsable API and any API calls.

More info: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication

---

If you're instead asking how to do something like issue **API keys**, DRF's `TokenAuthentication` can do that for you. You'll just need to add a view to your site that allows users to retrieve their generated tokens.

More info: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication